# The f:ajax listener method in h:selectOneMenu is not executed

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

The page is generated correctly with appropriate values in managed bean, but ajax events in these two h:selectOneMenus don't works. Listener is not called. An error has to be somewhere within  tags, but I don't see it.

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:messages />
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">

            <h:outputLabel value="Choose your faculty: *" for="faculties" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="faculties" value="#{registrateStudent.selectedFaculty}" >
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{registrateStudent.genSpecializations}" execute="faculties" render="specializations" />                        
                <f:selectItems value="#{registrateStudent.listFaculty}" var="curFac" itemLabel="#{curFac.name}" itemValue="#{curFac}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message id="message_faculties" for="faculties" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Choose your specialization: *" for="specializations" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="specializations" value="#{registrateStudent.selectedSpecialization}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{registrateStudent.listSpecialization}" var="curSpec" itemLabel="#{curSpec.name}" itemValue="#{curSpec}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message id="message_specializations" for="specializations" />
```

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "registrateStudent")
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrateStudent {


    private Faculty selectedFaculty;
    private List<Faculty> listFaculty;
    private Specialization selectedSpecialization;
    private List<Specialization> listSpecialization;
    private boolean showSpecialization = false;


    /** Creates a new instance of RegistrateStudent */
    public RegistrateStudent() {
        users = new Users();
        System.out.println("poaposd1");
        student = new Student();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listFaculty = ff.findAll();
        if (listFaculty != null) {
            selectedFaculty = listFaculty.get(0);
            listSpecialization = sf.findByFaculty(selectedFaculty.getIdFaculty());
            if (listSpecialization != null) {
                selectedSpecialization = listSpecialization.get(0);
            }
            else {}
        } else {}
    }

   public void genSpecializations(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        if (sf.findByFaculty(selectedFaculty.getIdFaculty()) != null) {
            this.showSpecialization = true;
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("faculties", "We don't have specializations for such faculty");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found out a few interesting things:

`<f:ajax>` tag doesn't work at `<h:link>`, `<h:selectOneMenu>`, `<h:button>`, `<h:commandButton>`. In this cases incorrect values in `render` attribute is not noticed, but incorrect value of `event` attribute generate an error.

`<h:outputLabel>`, `<h:inputText>` work with `<f:ajax>` properly

Comment: did you try execute="@this" instead of execute="faculties"?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` requires `jsf.js` file being included in the HTML `<head>`. It contains all JS functions for doing the JSF ajax magic.

To achieve this, ensure that you're using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in the master template. JSF will then automatically include the necessary `<script>` element there pointing to `jsf.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Look, with h:head</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Put your content here.
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Note that in a bit decent webbrowser with a bit decent webdeveloper toolset like Firefox's [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) and/or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) you should immediately have noticed JS errors like `jsf is undefined` when the ajax request is to be executed. That should at least have given something to think about.

---

**Update**: as per your update

> I've found out a few interesting things:
>
> `<f:ajax>` tag doesn't work at `<h:link>`, `<h:selectOneMenu>`, `<h:button>`, `<h:commandButton>`. In this cases incorrect values in `render` attribute is not noticed, but incorrect value of `event` attribute generate an error.
>
> `<h:outputLabel>`, `<h:inputText>` work with `<f:ajax>` properly.

The `<h:link>` and `<h:button>` are intented for GET requests only, not POST requests. It should however work just fine on `<h:selectOneMenu>` and `<h:commandButton>`. Don't you have more code into the complete picture which you omitted from the question for simplicity? Which JSF impl/version are you using? Are you using the right libraries in classpath? It look like that you must really have messed up something.

To convince you (and myself) I just created the following copy'n'paste'n'runnable testcase

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>SO question 6089924</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selected}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select..." />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="one" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="three" />
                <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" render="result" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        
            <h:commandButton value="commandButton" action="#{bean.submit}">
                <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" render="result" />
            </h:commandButton>
        
            <h:outputText id="result" value="#{bean.selected} #{bean.result}" />
            
            <h:messages />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

with this bean

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private String selected;
    private String result;

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("submit");
    }
    
    public void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("listener");
        result = "called by " + event.getComponent().getClass().getName();
    }

    public String getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(String selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

It runs fine with Mojarra 2.1.1 on Tomcat 7.0.12.

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.1 (FCS 20110408) for context '/playground'
```

Comment: thanks for example. i suppose `value="#{bean.selected}"` is not mapped to bean's property when I move `<h:form>` tag under `<h:selectOneMenu>` because of POST request? and why h:outputLabel doesn't work without h:form even if the elements is not in this h:form?

Comment: HTML input elements like `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` **needs** to go in a HTML `<form>` in order to get the values sent to the server. The same story applies to JSF (since all it basically does is generating a bunch of HTML). In your original question code snippet you had it right. All JSF components representing HTML input elements are in a form already. The `<h:outputLabel>` just renders a HTML `<label>` element which has no semantic form input value. You can however bind onclick actions to it.

Comment: @BalusC I've noticed that when using #{null} the "#{bean.listener}" doesn't get executed at all, how do we explain this? Is it a best practice to represent an empty selection by #{null}?

Comment: @BalusC when I use `itemValue=0` the method is called, when I set `itemValue` to `#{null}` the method is not executed (I tested with prints on console). I don't think it has a relation with the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you have `f:metadata` and `f:viewparam` tags since the setters of the parameters will be called with every ajax request.

Can you provide the error log if there is any error/exception that is being generated when you call the ajax call?

Comment: there is no any error or exception. Also I just noticed that when I change the first h:selectOneMenu, another is re-rendered, as it should, but listener is still not called.

Comment: can you put a System.out.println just at the beginning of the method to make sure that it is really not being called?