# How to set <selectOneMenu> value to bean variable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am trying to set the value of `<h:selectOneMenu>` using the bean setter, but it is not working. Here is my .xml code:

```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{adminActionController.tempBean.selectType}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Check" itemValue="Check" />
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cash" itemValue="Cash"/>
      <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{adminActionController.tempBean.changeType}"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

And here is my bean code:

```
protected String selectType;

public String getSelectType() {
    return selectType;
}

public void setSelectType(String selectType) {
    this.selectType = selectType;
}
```

I tried a lot of ways, but something is still missing. I don't know what.
It sets `h:inputText` values to bean, but I have a problem with dropdown values. 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without immediate="true".And selectOneMenu must be inside h:form.When selectOneMenu is changed,your listener is working,right ?

Comment: inside h:form thre is :datatable  :rowexpansion :selectOneMenu
and also my :ajax listener is not hitting onChange event.
On same page :inputText it is working(setting values) bt problem with this tag

Comment: Listener from same bean_____  
    

    public void changeType(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("tempBean:&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        System.out.println("cubeChanged: " + ((HtmlSelectOneMenu) event.getComponent()).getSubmittedValue());
    }

Comment: try removing AjaxBehaviorEvent as parameter and try .

Comment: without AjaxBehaviorEvent, it should be S.O.P msg in tomcat .. but it is not showing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089924/the-fajax-listener-method-in-hselectonemenu-is-not-executed

Comment: Try to avoid forms-nesting if you have any.