# JSF, selectOneMenu and Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, selectonemenu

I have selectOneMenu in JavaServer Faces:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{addressesBean.getMemberRole(user.id)}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{addressesBean.allRoles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.title}"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{addressesBean.updateMemberRole}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in Address bean I have simply listener:

```
public void updateMemberRole(){

   System.err.println("TEST");

}
```

So, byt when I change values in selectbox, nothing gonna happens... Message TEST don't prints... Why? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `listener="#{addressesBean.updateMemberRole()}"` already? Unrelated: are you *sure* JSF will be able to write to `getMemberRole()`? You might not be able to submit this component.

Comment: Did see read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089924/the-fajax-listener-method-in-hselectonemenu-is-not-executed

Comment: Have you included the `h:selectOneMenu` inside `h:form` ?

Comment: Yeap, `h:selectOneMenu` is in form. So problem is in `value="#{addressesBean.getMemberRole(user.id)}"` when I have changed this to `<h:selectOneMenu value="#{addressesBean.memberRole}">` (simply bean field with getter and setter), then ajax event executes, but I need to get correct selected value depending on user ID.